# Svelte: Invalidate a store

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, svelte, sveltekit

I'm building my own form management in Svelte and I use stores to display messages.

I have something like (this is Pug):

```
+if('$successMsg')
    FormMsg(className='success-msg', msg!='{$successMsg}')
```

Then, in my `FormMsg` component, I have a button to close the message:

```
+if('active')
    div(class!='{className}', transition:fade!='{{duration: 500}}')
        | {msg}
        .close(on:click!='{handleClose}') ✕
```

And my `FormMsg` JS looks like this:

```js
import {fade} from 'svelte/transition';

export let className;
export let msg;

let active = true;

let handleClose = () => {
    active = false;
}
```

The thing is, if a user saves a form twice, I want to show the `FormMsg` again.

I use:

```js
successMsg.set('The form has been saved');
```

It works well when the `successMsg` store is set for the first time, but it does not work on the second time if the message has been previously closed.
I guess the component is not recreated and keeps `active = false`.

I have tried using `component.$destroy()` on the `FormMsg`, but I would not get the fade transition then.

Any idea how I could handle this better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, partly thanks to khromov from the Svelte discord.

Actually, you can pass a store as prop, so I can call the component like this:

```
FormMsg(className='success-msg', msg!='{successMsg}')
```

Then I can use it in my component pug:

```
+if('$msg')
    div(class!='{className}', transition:fade!='{{duration: 500}}')
        | {$msg}
        .close(on:click!='{handleClose}') ✕
```

And my component JS :

```js
import {fade} from 'svelte/transition';

export let className;
export let msg;

let handleClose = () => {
    msg.set(false);
}
```

Problem solved!